# Prove $[\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}]=[\sqrt{4x+2}], x \in \Bbb N$

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

prove that $[\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}]=[\sqrt{4x+2}], x  \in \Bbb N$.  Could someone help me to solve. I try many ways but I can't solve it ( I tried : Let $x=n^2 +k$ and don't know what to do afterwards).

Comment: See also: [For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\lfloor{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}\rfloor} = \lfloor{\sqrt{4n+2}\rfloor}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6087).