# Prove the equality $[\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}]=[\sqrt{4n+2}]$.

Tags: number-theory, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm reading Apostol Analytic Number Theory, the question ask me to prove for positive integer $n$,  $$[\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}]=[\sqrt{4n+2}].$$
My approach is, define $f(n)=[\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}]$, after some examination I try to prove that for any positive integer $k$,

\begin{align}f(k^2)&=f(k^2+1)\\
&=\cdots\\
&=f(k^2+k-1) \\
&=2k
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
f(k^2+k)&=f(k^2+k+1)\\
&=\cdots\\
&=f(k^2+2k)\\
&=2k+1.
\end{align}

Indeed, let $r$ be an integer with $0\leq r\leq k-1$, then $$\sqrt{k^2+r}+\sqrt{k^2+r+1}\geq k+k=2k,$$
and by Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, for any positive numbers $a,b$ we have $\sqrt a+\sqrt b\leq \sqrt{2a+2b}$, therefore \begin{align*}\sqrt{k^2+r}+\sqrt{k^2+r+1}&\leq \sqrt{k^2+k-1}+\sqrt{k^2+k}\\
&\leq \sqrt{2k^2+2k-2+2k^2+2k}\\
&=\sqrt{4k^2+4k-2}\\
&< \sqrt{4k^2+4k+1}\\
&=2k+1\end{align*}
So the first part is proved. 
Turning to the second part, I have tried for a very long time and finally come up with this: I let $r$ be any integer with $k\leq r\leq 2k$
\begin{align*}\sqrt{k^2+k+1}&\geq \sqrt{k^2+k}\\2\sqrt{(k^2+k)(k^2+k+1)}&\geq 2k^2+2k\\
k^2+k+2\sqrt{(k^2+k)(k^2+k+1)}+k^2+k+1&\geq 4k^2+4k+1\\\therefore (\sqrt{k^2+k}+\sqrt{k^2+k+1})^2&\geq (2k+1)^2\\
\sqrt{k^2+r}+\sqrt{k^2+r+1}\geq\sqrt{k^2+k}+\sqrt{k^2+k+1}&\geq 2k+1\end{align*}
also that $$\sqrt{k^2+r}+\sqrt{k^2+r+1}\leq \sqrt{k^2+2k}+\sqrt{k^2+2k+1}< 2k+2$$
This complete the propositions. 
The remaining is to prove whenever is it the same as $[\sqrt{4n+2}]$, I let $n=k^2+r$ for some $0\leq r\leq k-1$, then

\begin{align}
2k&\leq \sqrt{4k^2+2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{4n+2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{4k^2+4k-2}\\
&< 2k+1.
\end{align}

Then let $n=k^2+r$ for some $k\leq r\leq 2k$,

\begin{align}
2k+1&\leq \sqrt{4k^2+4k+2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{4n+2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{4k^2+8k+2}\\
&< 2k+2.
\end{align}

Since any positive integer $n$ can be expressed as $k^2+r$ where $k$ is some integer and $r$ is either in $0\leq r\leq k-1$ or $k\leq r\leq 2k$, I have proved the equality. 
Above is my complete solution, I use a step stone to achieve the goal, and there is a lot of heavy machinery like Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and others. Is there any straight forward proof? Like immediately use some elegant tool to bring me from LHS to the RHS?

Comment: Various solutions at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1542728/42969.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should now be reading them.

Comment: How are you able to go from $\sqrt{k^2+r}+\sqrt{k^2+r+1}\le\sqrt{4k^2+4k-2}$ to $\sqrt{k^2+r}+\sqrt{k^2+r+1}<\sqrt{4k^2+4k+1}$?

Comment: @HenryLee Just simply $4k^2+4k-2< 4k^2+4k+1$.