# Reference Request for solution of Ramanujan Identities

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Where can I find the identities of Ramanujan concerning the Floor Function with its solution? Any site you can recomend to me? [image]

Comment: http://science.ncue.edu.tw/journal/article/1-2-7.pdf

Comment: (iii) Can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/for-n-in-mathbbn-lfloor-sqrtn-sqrtn1-rfloor-lfloor-sqrt4n

Answer (score 3):

For (i), write $n=6k+r$ where $r\in \{0,1,...,5\}$. Then left side is $$\begin{eqnarray}\Big[{n\over 3}\Big]+ \Big[{n+2\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{n+4\over 6}\Big] &= &\Big[{6k+r\over 3}\Big]+ \Big[{6k+r+2\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{6k+r+4\over 6}\Big]\\
&= &2k+\Big[{r\over 3}\Big]+ k+\Big[{r+2\over 6}\Big]+k+\Big[{r+4\over 6}\Big]\\
&= &4k+\underbrace{\Big[{r\over 3}\Big]+\Big[{r+2\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{r+4\over 6}\Big]}_{E_r}\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
$$E_r=\left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    0, & r=0,1\\
    1, & r=2 \\
2, & r=3 \\
3, & r=4,5 \\
\end{array}%
\right.$$
And the right side is
$$\begin{eqnarray}\Big[{n\over 2}\Big]+ \Big[{n+3\over 6}\Big]&= &\Big[{6k+r\over 2}\Big]+ \Big[{6k+r+3\over 6}\Big]\\
&= &3k+\Big[{r\over 2}\Big]+ k+\Big[{r+3\over 6}\Big]\\
&= &4k+\underbrace{\Big[{r\over 2}\Big]+\Big[{r+3\over 6}\Big]}_{F_r}\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
$$F_r=\left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    0, & r=0,1\\
    1, & r=2 \\
2, & r=3 \\
3, & r=4,5 \\
\end{array}%
\right.$$
So both sides are the same for all $r$ and we are done.

Comment: Why did you just let $n=6k+r$? Is this the general form of an positive integer?

Comment: That is correct. If we had $[n/11]$ then I would write $n=11k+r$ and $0\leq r\leq 10$

Comment: oh, I get it! You did that for convenience since in the denominator there is a $6$. If it were some arbitrary number un the denominator like $m$, then I consider the integer $n=mk+r$ where 0\leqr\ls

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't edit the last comment. I tried to say that $n=mk+r$ where $r$ is an integer between $0$ and $m-1$.

Comment: I can understand now! Thanks for the feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

If $[x]$ denotes floor we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\Big[{n+ks+t\over ms}\Big]=\Big[{n+t\over s}\Big]$$
for $n\geqslant0$, $m>0$, $s>t\geqslant0$, $n,m,s,t$ - integers. So
$$\Big[{n\over 2}\Big]=\Big[{n\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{n+2\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{n+4\over 6}\Big]$$
$$\Big[{n\over 3}\Big]=\Big[{n\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{n+3\over 6}\Big]$$
and obviously
$$\Big[{n\over 3}\Big]+\Big[{n+2\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{n+4\over 6}\Big]=\Big[{n\over 2}\Big]+\Big[{n+3\over 6}\Big]$$
With same conditions for $n,m,s,t$ if $[x]$ denotes ceiling we have
$$\Big[{n\over 3}\Big]+\Big[{n+2\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{n+4\over 6}\Big]=\Big[{n+2\over 2}\Big]+\Big[{n+3\over 6}\Big]$$
and also if $[x]$ denotes nearest integer we have
$$\Big[{n+2\over 3}\Big]+\Big[{n+2\over 6}\Big]+\Big[{n+4\over 6}\Big]=\Big[{n+2\over 2}\Big]+\Big[{n+3\over 6}\Big]$$